# Why to define compactness with sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness

We defined compactness by can be covered by finite open sets, then we introduced a sequence definition.

Why to define compactness again with sequence?
What's the use of sequentially compactness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define compactness for sets contained in more general spaces than just $\mathbb{R}$. And then, there is a difference between compactness and sequential compactness.

Comment: is compactness and sequential compactness the same in R^n?

Comment: i think our prof said compactness and sequential compactness are the same in a metric space?

Comment: Yes, you need much "uglier" spaces. The easiest example I can offer is the weak-* topology on the (continuous) dual of $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: Yes, it coincides on metric spaces.

Comment: does the metric spaces have to be R? or if it is a complex metric spaces then it also holds?

Comment: It does hold for all metric spaces.

Answer (score 0):

When applicable, sequential compactness is often much easier to prove than compactness.

Comment: And also more convenient to apply.

Comment: And also more intuitive IMO. The history of the subject bears this out.